# My spring-boot program doesn't have the JavaBuilder in the Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, ide, spring-tool-suite

I loaded a project on Spring-tool Suite but I realized that it does not correct the errors. Going to see Properties I realized that all the parameters related to the JavaBuilder that I have in the other loaded projects were missing. I think it's a Jdk problem, but I don't know how to set everything up or how to reset the project in order to have the error corrected.

thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Spring-Tool itself which had a bug where it didn't show any kind of error. There are two ways to get around the problem: delete the project from Spring-boot, delete the Workspace and reload everything. In case it is also recommended to download Spring-boot tool Suite again. In the second case it could be an error importing the project, try to import it to Intellij or another IDEE and see if you have the same problems. If you have the same problems it is a problem of loading the java libraries. To solve it you should open another project where you have no problems and once opened, go to **FILE-> NEW-> IMPORT PROJECT** and import your project.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to delete the `.metadata` folder in your workspace.